# Adding a link to a <td> element while parsing json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Another noob question/issue.....I am currently parsing a json file and appending the data to an HTML table. I need to make one of the name/value pairs (COPD_QUAL.FIN) display as a link within the table.

Here is my function to append the data....

```
function createPatientTable(json) {
$.each(json.LIST, function(i, COPD_QUAL) {
    $('.footable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + COPD_QUAL.PATIENT + '</td><td><a href="javascript:APPLINK(0,"powerchart.exe","/PERSONID=8986122 /ENCNTRID=14150574")">' + COPD_QUAL.FIN + '</a></td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.NURSE_UNIT + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.ROOM + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.BED +'</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.ATTENDING_PHYS + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.LENGTH_OF_STAY + '</td><td class="assessment ' + getSeverity(COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS) + '">' + COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS + '</td></tr>');
});
$('.footable').footable();
};
```

This is the part I am trying to make a link but receiving a syntax error when clicking the link within the application that I included the table within:

```
'</td><td><a href="javascript:APPLINK(0,"powerchart.exe","/PERSONID=8986122 /ENCNTRID=14150574")">'
```

If I try to use single ' instead of the double " within the () of the APPLINK function, I receive an unexpected ) error:

```
'</td><td><a href="javascript:APPLINK(0,'powerchart.exe','/PERSONID=8986122 /ENCNTRID=14150574')">' + COPD_QUAL.FIN + '</a></td><td>'
```

Could someone help me with the syntax? Am I completely off here? I was able to get the link to work otuside of the table in a  random div but I cannot append the link to the table within my json function. Here is the hardcoded / standalone div link that works:

```
<a href="javascript:APPLINK(0,'powerchart.exe','/PERSONID=8986122 /ENCNTRID=14150574')">Open patient chart test2</a>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: IMO you should let the syntax error help you fix the syntax, and use stack overflow to help explain the syntax error if you don't understand it. Long story short, plz post the syntax error too.

Comment: The link only throws a "syntax error" within the application....which does not have any debugging tools. So it literally only says "syntax error". It does not throw a syntax error outside of the application. The link simply does not go anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'</td><td><a href="javascript:APPLINK(0,\'powerchart.exe\',\'/PERSONID=8986122 /ENCNTRID=14150574\')">' + COPD_QUAL.FIN + '</a></td><td>'
```

or

```
'</td><td><a href="javascript:APPLINK(0,\\"powerchart.exe\\",\\"/PERSONID=8986122 /ENCNTRID=14150574\\")">'
```

You need to escape the quotes.

Comment: What if I wanted to include one of the json name/value pairs instead of the hardcoded PERSONID=8986122 and ENCNTRID=14150574? I tried using  PERSONID=COPD_QUAL.PERSON_ID and ENCNTRID=COPD_QUAL.ENCNTR_ID but it did not work. How should that be formatted?

Comment: replace `8986122` with `'+COPD_QUAL.PERSON_ID+'` and `14150574` with `'+COPD_QUAL.ENCNTR_ID+'`

Comment: Haha....I was trying  + COPD_QUAL.ENCNTR_ID + .......I was missing the single ' and had spaces. Thank you so much for your help! This worked again.